# Open modal dialog in WPF to get credentials for CefSharp

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I have a WPF application which is hosting a conversation window from skype for business; the window can open an child control, a Chromiun web browser (CefSharp).
The browser opens a site that needs credentials, so the method GetAuthCredentials is override in order to process the request.
The code goes like this:

```
AuthBox dlg = new AuthBox(); 
dlg.Owner = _parent;
dlg.ShowDialog();
callback.Continue(dlg.Username, dlg.Password);
```

The problem is: I need to make this dialog as modal, in order to lock the parent window (the conversation); for that reason, dlg.Owner = _parent; is added. However this throws an exception:
 System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

To use dispatcher.BeginInvoke doesn't work.
Is there any other way to open the login window (modal) avoiding this threading issue?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume dispatcher.BeginInvoke doesn't work for you because it doesn't block?
Try using a synchronization primitive, such as ManualResetEvent, open the dialog in UI thread, in calling thread wait for ManualResetEvent notification, and make sure dialog raises the event when done.